# How to install Tailwind in Vue3 + Vite?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vite

I followed these instructions exactly:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

but the dropdown that's supposed to look like this:

https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/elements/dropdowns

still looks like garbage:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJqdu.png

---

I installed Tailwind and used init:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KniW.jpg

I filled in the "tailwind.config.js" like this:

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/components/DropdownVue/DropdownVue.vue"], <---INCLUDED  DROPDOWN FILE
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I created an "index.css" and imported the Tailwind modules in it like this:

**index.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;  <-----INCLUDED IMPORTS
@tailwind utilities;

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Noto Serif", serif, Ariel, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #d7d7d7;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif&display=swap");
```

I started the build process and got an "output.css" file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPGFB.png

that I included in my "index.html" file like this:

```
<link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and at that point you are supposed to be done and your Tailwind components should be working according to those instructions.

BUT, they didn't work and I then found a more specific page for installing Tailwind with Vue + Vite:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite

and the directions are pretty much the same, only it says to npm install like this:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

and previously I only installed "tailwindcss". So I ran the install on the other 2 packages hoping that would fix it, but it didn't.

---

What part did I get wrong here? Can someone help me fix this?

This is all the relevant code again:

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/components/DropdownVue/DropdownVue.vue"], <---INCLUDED FILE
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**index.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;  <-----INCLUDED IMPORTS
@tailwind utilities;

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Noto Serif", serif, Ariel, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #d7d7d7;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif&display=swap");
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <NavBar :clicked="clicked" @toggleDrawer="toggleMenu()" />
  <BackDrop :clicked="clicked" />
  <SideDrawer :clicked="clicked" />
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<style>
@import "./index.css";  <-------IMPORTED STYLES
</style>
```

**DropdownVue.vue (THE TAILWIND COMPONENT IM TRYING TO USE)**

```
<template>
  <Menu as="div" class="relative inline-block text-left">
    <div>
      <MenuButton
        class="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-100"
      >
        Options
        <ChevronDownIcon class="-mr-1 ml-2 h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
      </MenuButton>
    </div>

    <transition
      enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-100"
      enter-from-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
      enter-to-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
      leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-75"
      leave-from-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
      leave-to-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
    >
      <MenuItems
        class="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-56 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none"
      >
        <div class="py-1">
          <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
            <a
              href="#"
              :class="[
                active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700',
                'block px-4 py-2 text-sm',
              ]"
              >Account settings</a
            >
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
            <a
              href="#"
              :class="[
                active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700',
                'block px-4 py-2 text-sm',
              ]"
              >Support</a
            >
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
            <a
              href="#"
              :class="[
                active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700',
                'block px-4 py-2 text-sm',
              ]"
              >License</a
            >
          </MenuItem>
          <form method="POST" action="#">
            <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
              <button
                type="submit"
                :class="[
                  active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700',
                  'block w-full px-4 py-2 text-left text-sm',
                ]"
              >
                Sign out
              </button>
            </MenuItem>
          </form>
        </div>
      </MenuItems>
    </transition>
  </Menu>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Menu, MenuButton, MenuItem, MenuItems } from "@headlessui/vue";
import { ChevronDownIcon } from "@heroicons/vue/20/solid";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `content` property in your `tailwind.config.js` should be:

```
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
```

Comment: Do I have to do anything after I change it to that? I edited the content section with what you put but it's still not taking effect. Do I have to run build again?

Comment: Try running "npm run dev" and changes should take effect. If you are still having problems start a new Vue 3 project using Vite and then follow the tailwind instructions and if this works then copy your original code across to it.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project 
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite#vue